# Django execute a custom function from Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am new to Django and have gone through the [first Django App](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) tutorial.I understand the separate bits but am not able to form a complete solution.

My requirement is to add a custom button to a Model's Change List Page in Admin, redirect it to a confirmation page, execute a function on confirmation and then redirect to the change list page with execution status.

I have added the custom button but am lost after that. 
Currently this is what I am doing:

Changed the admin class list template

```
class ReconciliationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'SalesReconciliation/change_list.html'
```

This is my change list template:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_static %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
{{ block.super }}
<li>
    <a href={% url 'admin:reconcileConfirm'%} class="btn btn-high btn-success">Run Reconciliation</a>
</li>
{% endblock %}
```

Changed the **urls.py** in the main app as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^reconcileConfirm/", include("SalesReconciliation.urls")),
]
```

Changed the **urls.py** in the child app as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^reconcileConfirm/', views.ReconcileConfirm, name='ReconcileConfirm')
]
```

In the **views.py** of the child app added the follows:

```
def ReconcileConfirm(request):
    return HttpResponse("..something")
```

I am hoping that this would work like:

> Click on Run Reconciliation link -> Main urls.py routes to child
>   urls.py -> child urls.py routes to views.py -> function in views py
>   performs some operations

But I am getting the following errors:

> NoReverseMatch at /SalesReconciliation/reconciliation/ Reverse for 'reconcileConfirm' not found. 'reconcileConfirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
>
> Request Method: GET
>
> Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/SalesReconciliation/reconciliation/
>
> Django Version: 2.0.4
>
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
>
> Exception Value: Reverse for 'reconcileConfirm' not found.
>
> 'reconcileConfirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Also I would like to know whether it is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

In your template:

```
{% url 'admin:reconcileConfirm'%}
```

in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^reconcileConfirm/', views.ReconcileConfirm, name='ReconcileConfirm')
]
```

Note that `ReconcileConfirm` is different from `reconcileConfirm`. This is probably the first error to fix in order to achieve what you want to.